# When using OLS on DataFrames how do you get the corresponding columns names in params

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have the following code:

```
X = smapi.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(lpca1.components_.T, index = lr.index))
m = smapi.OLS(Y, X).fit()
b = m.params
```

In `b` the column names does not correspond to that in `Y`. How do I get the same labels for each set of data and regression variables in the results? Currently the regression variables are labels are appearing (`X` column labels) but not for the different datasets (`Y` column labels).

Comment: Would be great if you gave the module you're importing and an example of the output - even if they're mock values it would help solving this quicker

Comment: Y is your dependent variable, it should only have one label.